# Proving Riemann integral property for $f(x) \leq g(x)$ on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ such that $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. I want to prove that $\int_a^bf \leq \int_a^{b}g$. My intuition is that if I take $h(x) = g(x)-f(x)$, then $h$ is a non-negative function, and hence $\int_a^b h \geq 0$. By linearity of Riemann integral, it follows that $\int_a^bf \leq \int_a^{b}g$. But I can't use the fact that Riemann integral of positive function is positive since we did not formally prove it.  All I have done now is that for Riemann sums, we have $S(f;\dot{\mathcal{P}}) \leq S(g;\dot{\mathcal{P}})$ for tagged partition $\dot{\mathcal{P}}$ of mesh $< \delta$. How can I finish the proof?

Comment: Here is the full-proof of "if $h \geq 0$ then $\int h \geq 0$": simply observe that if $h \geq 0$ is integrable, then any $\sup h([\tau_{i-1}, \tau_i]) \geq 0.$ Q.E.D.